# Adding c# code to existing .net core project with Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

Is it possible to load an existing .NET core project with Roslyn API, add a c# class and save it so the file is actually created on disk and added to the project.
I tried to do it with MSBuildWorkspace and AddDocument and TryApplyChanges method - I can load the solution and project  but the file is not created (and I don't get any exception or error).

Where can I find a working example that shows how to use Roslyn to accomplish something like that

Comment: Roslyn is for analyzing and compiling source code, but you want a code file to be physically created in your working folder. Can you do this with a VS Code extension?

Comment: No, I have to do it from a console app. I need Roslyn's functionalities for analysing the code so it would be great if i could update the solution with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSBuildWorkspace](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs,29) does not implement any of the 'add' functionality. It should be thought of as a 'read-only' view of the solution and its code.

[AdhocWorkspace](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/AdhocWorkspace.cs,17) does allow adding and removing projects and documents, but it does not have some of the same capabilities as MSBuildWorkspace (AdhocWorkspace cannot handle Xaml files for example).

Comment: Thanks. Any working example how to do it with AdhocWorkspace?

Comment: MS documentation says for AdhocWorkspace "A workspace that allows full manipulation of projects and documents, but does not persist changes."